# Display 2 div in block and vertical div beside them

Tags: html, css

I am trying to design a section which 3 image. I can get the two images to display by block easily. I can float the third image to the right and adjust the height easily. However my issue is it does not align side by side.Below is an example of what I am trying to achieve

[image]

This is an example of what I have so far

```css
.image-one,
.image-two {
  width: 250px;
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.image-three {
  float: right;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-one">Hello</div>
  <div class="image-two">Image two</div>
  <div class="image-three"> Image three </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you use CSS grid, or flexbox? Given the html you posted seems to bear no relation to the displayed image, which element in your html should be where in the finished page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to simple add flex to the container, and then add the content within a left and a right div.

Here's a working example:

```css
.container {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
}

.image-one,
.image-two {
  width: 250px;
  height: 95px;
  background-color: green;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.image-three {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 240px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="image-one">Hello</div>
    <div class="image-two">Image two</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="image-three"> Image three </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox for this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;            /* align items in columns */
  flex-wrap: wrap;                   /* wrap to a new column when height is reached */
  justify-content: space-between;    /* add spacing in  between top and bottom image */
  height: 210px;                     /* height of your 2 images plus and spacing you want */
  width: 510px;                      /* width of 2 columns plus any spacing */
}

.image-one,
.image-two {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  display: block;
}

.image-three {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 250px;
  height: 210px;                 /* I would make this image the height of the other 2 plus spacing */
  align-self:flex-end;           /* align this to the right of the container */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-one">Hello</div>
  <div class="image-two">Image two</div>
  <div class="image-three"> Image three </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add some internal divs like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="container-left">
        <div class="image-one">Hello</div>
        <div class="image-two">Image two</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-right">
         <div class="image-three"> Image three </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, add css to container-left and container-right to properly set the width and the float. Like this:

```
.container-left, .container-right{
    width:250px;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make use of bootstrap columns?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row main-row">
  <div class="col-6 left-col">
    <div class="row left-col-top">
     <!-- Top left image here -->
    </div>
    <div class="row left-col-bottom">
     <!-- Bottom left image here -->   
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 right-col">

  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main-row {
   height:300px;
}

.left-col-top {
 background-color:blue;
 height:50%;
}
.left-col-bottom {
 background-color:red;
 height:50%;
}
.right-col {
 background-color:green;
 height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy flexbox solution :)

```css
#main, #left {
  display:flex;
}

#left {
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.section {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="left">
    <div class="section">Hello</div>
    <div class="section">Hello</div>
  </div>
  <div id="right" class="section">Hello</div>
</div>
```